# Creating Font for X11

Tags: unicode, fonts, x11

How to create a font for Unicode characters for X windows system? Can anyone provide me some tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X11 understands TrueType, OpenType and Type 1 (PostScript) fonts. If you want to create a new font you should probably use one of these formats.

There's also the legacy bitmap format, but its use is not recommended as these fonts are not scalable and do not support anti-aliasing.

There's a number of tools for creating TrueType and other scalable fonts, [FontForge](http://fontforge.org) being the prominent open-source one.